# Grunt usemin issue: unable to process the task.required config property concat.generated missing

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I have a folder structure like this

```
app
|
+- html
|   +- index.html
+- assets
|   +- js
|      +- foo.js
|      +- bar.js
+- dist
```

My Gruntfile.js is

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    config: {
      app: 'app',
      dist: 'dist'
    },
    useminPrepare: {
      html: 'html/index.html',
      options: {
        root: '<%= config.app %>',
        dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
      }
    },
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= config.dist %>/html/index.html'],
      js: '<%= config.dist %>/assets/js/*.js'
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-rev');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-usemin');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify'); 

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
     'useminPrepare',
     'concat:generated',
     'cssmin:generated',
     'uglify:generated',
     'usemin'
  ]);
};
```

in html/index.html

```
<!-- build:js /assets/js/optimized.js -->
<script src="/assets/js/foo.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/bar.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

When I execute the 'grunt build' command, it shows "unable to process the task.required config property concat.generated missing" error.
What could be the reason?

Comment: In my case it was because I was using the default setup (same as your build) but I had no build:js block in my index. So usemin did not configure the uglify task and thus it failed when trying to call in as part of 'build'. Simple fix either add in build:js block or remove the uglify task from 'build'

Answer (score 1):

If your Gruntfile.js is in a root location, then you have wrong html path in useminPrepare task. I'm not sure if useminPrepare understands 'root' option. Try this:

```js
useminPrepare: {
      html: 'app/html/index.html',
      options: {
        dest: '<%= config.dist %>'
      }
    }
```